# Page loading in Robot Framework chromedriver is too slow compared to Python selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Good day,

I ran into issue with Robot Framework RPA.Browser.Selenium, Chrome:
Some elements are loading extremely slow (up to 20 seconds per element). I dont believe its related to cache or network since I tried same script in python WebDriver and have 10 times faster results in comparison.

So today I figured out my Robot Framework is using x86-x64 translated version of Google Chrome unlike python Selenium which uses arm64. I only have one chromedriver installed or at least that I installed myself and specified in $PATH. But that had no effect.

I would appreciate any help on how I can fix this.

Device: Macbook Air M1